# Don't know how to create a function file cpp on visual studio (c++)

Tags: function, visual-c++

I am new in c++ language and have a problem in how to create a file for a function to use it (I know I can create it within a class I just need to create cpp file and header file for a function so I can use it within the main function like this screen shots [enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/6KiQ4.png)

This is my code that cannot run because as I think I didn't declare the function in a separate cpp file so it be treated as object and the linker link them together(I think that based on my poor knowledge )

```
#include "stdafx.h"
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include <conio.h>
using namespace std;

int PassByValue(int a);


int main()
{
    int num1 = 1;
    int *pNum = new int;
    *pNum = 5;

    int PassByValue(int a){
        string op = "The name of this fuction is PassByValue";
        cout << op << endl;
        return 0;
    }



    return 0;
}
```

How I can use the function without getting compiler errors (c1010--c2601)
can any one tell me whats wrong with the code and how to fix it? 
With my regards

Comment: Move the function definition out of `main`, to where the declaration currently is. As in, `#include ...  int PassByValue(int a){ ... } int main() { ... }`

Comment: Thx for your respond its worked :)